# Export mesh as CSV file

Tags: blender

I know you can import a 3d mesh into blender thanks to this script http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?211735-A-Script-to-Import-a-CSV-File-and-Create-Meshes-(for-Blender-2-5x-or-later)

However is it also possible to export a mesh as a CSV file..?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no proper CSV export script but you can get almost the same result exporting with the raw format.
Go to user preferences, Addon, search for raw install. After it's available under file/export. 
For convenience you can rename it with the csv extension